# SQL Server - fast way to delete records based on a table join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Normally I would truncate the data like this:

```
truncate table DST.BreaksDST
```

However, I need to only delete data in which a join to another table contains a source of 'DST'

My `SELECT` statement looks like this:

```
select 
    dstid, dst.breakid 
from 
    DST.BreaksDST dst 
join 
    base.breaks b on dst.BreakId = b.BreakId
where 
    b.source = 'DST'
```

So I know that If I use something like `DELETE .... IN (select dst.breakid .....)`

That would be very slow, right?

What is a better way?

Comment: It really depends on how much of the table you're deleting. If you're deleting a very high percentage of the table, it might be faster to SELECT out the records you want to keep into  a new table, drop the original table and rename the new table. If not, then the DELETE FROM INNER JOIN syntax works well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `DELETE [FROM] ... FROM JOIN`:

```
DELETE dst
FROM DST.BreaksDST dst 
JOIN base.breaks b
   ON dst.BreakId = b.BreakId
WHERE b.source = 'DST';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a575befacd5ae0d02dd7a2a9ff1f655)**

Please note that double`FROM` is not an error:

```
DELETE FROM dst
FROM BreaksDST dst 
JOIN breaks b
   ON dst.BreakId = b.BreakId
WHERE b.source = 'DST';
```

Comment: For reference this is the syntax to use and you can replace DELETE dst with UPDATE dst SET dst.x=b.y with the same join syntax for UPDATES.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Actually double `FROM` was intended. But thanks for your edit, I made it more explicit.